# Deriving $\sin{ix}=i\sinh{x}$

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

> Derive $\sin{ix}=i\sinh{x}$ from $(5)$. What is $\sin{i}$?
>   $$\cos{x}=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad\sin{x}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)\tag 5$$

We have
$$\begin{align}
\sin{ix}&=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{i^2x}-e^{-i^2x}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{-x}-e^x\right)\\
&=-\frac{\sinh{x}}{i}
\end{align}$$
It does not look like what we are deriving. What went wrong?

Comment: Then you just need $i^2=-1$ i.e. $-\frac 1i=i$

Comment: @MarkBennet Now I see. Thank you. This exercise is from a calculus book, and I have just started to see imaginary numbers.

Comment: This is exercise 6.7.59 from Strang's *Calculus*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Re-arrangement* of the **representation** of your result:

$$\boxed{\begin{align}
\sin{ix} = -\frac{\sinh{x}}{i} = (-1)\cdot \frac{\sinh{x}}{i} = (i^2)\cdot \frac{\sinh{x}}{i} = i\sinh x 
\end{align}}$$

Answer (score 6):

Multiply
 the denominator and the numerator by $i.$

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track bro.

$$-\frac{\sinh x}{i} = i^2\frac{\sinh x}{i} = i\sinh x$$

Comment: I know this is an old post but I'm not sure why the original correct equation was edited to be incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

We know that $sinh(ix)=i sin(x)$.
                          Put $i=ix$
                   $$Sinh(i.ix)=isin(ix)$$
                  $$ Sinh(-x)=i sin(ix)$$
                   $$-sinhx=i sin(ix)$$
                  $$i\times isinhx=i sin(ix)$$
                    $$i sinhx=sin(ix)$$

Comment: ???????????????